# von Neumann subalgebra which is isomorphic to $R$

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $N$ be the von Neumann subalgebra of $M$.

If $N$ is $*$-isomorphic to the hyperfinite type II$_1$ factor $R$.
Can we conclude that $N$ is also a hyperfinite type II$_1$ factor?

Comment: I mean, you are saying $N$ is even *isomorphic* to the hyperfinite II$_1$ factor. Being hyperfinite and being a II$_1$ factor are properties preserved under isomorphism, so of course $N$ is also a hyperfinite II$_1$ factor.

Comment: If you meant to ask whether subfactors of the hyperfinite II$_1$ factor are hyperfinite II$_1$ factors, then that’s Martin’s answer - I should point out that $R$ also contains all matrix algebras as subfactors, but apart from those all subfactors are isomorphic to $R$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the only II$_1$-subfactors of the hyperfinite II$_1$-factor $R$  are copies  of $R$. This follows from Connes 1976 Annals' paper, where he proves that every injective II$_1$-factor is hyperfinite. So $R$ is injective, and because a $\text{II}_1$-factor has conditional expectations onto any of its subfactors, any subfactor of $R$ is injective and hence hyperfinite.

Comment: What does the "copies of  R" mean?

Comment: "Subfactors isomorphic to $R$". When one says "the" hyperfinite II$_1$-factor what one means is "a hyperfinite/injective II$_1$-factor". There are uncountably many of those, but they are all isomorphic.

Comment: When one uses the $R$, does it denote that the hyperfinite factor was constructed by tensor product of 2 by 2 matrices?

Comment: It doesn't matter.